# How can I preserve members of my old class when using implicit conversion casting to set a new value to my object?

Tags: c#

I know that some people will suggest other ways of performing this same function and I am only interested in specifically accomplishing my goal. I already have working code that performs said task and just would like to understand more about writing my own powerful objects - thank you.

My goal:

```
int x = 100;
Base b = new Base(0, 3);
b = x; // Preserves my baseNum of 3 for conversions
```

Code:

```
public class Base
{
    public int count = 0; // represents the count of current numerical value in base ten digit count : 3 -> could be read NEVER user changed
    public int baseNum = 10; // conversion base subscript -> """""
    public int represented; // represented base ten value of conversion (used for output NOT mathmatically friendly) -> should be read BUT never change by user
    public int numerical = 0;

    public int[] basearray; // should NOT be modified read only 

    public Base()
    {
        //count = 0; // setting numerical will run digit count
        baseNum = 10;
        numerical = 0;
    }

    public Base(int i)
    {
        baseNum = 10;
        numerical = i;
    }

    public Base(int n, int b)
    {
        baseNum = b;
        numerical = n;
    }

    public static implicit operator Base(int i)
    {
        // Help needed
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Base b)
    {
        int i = b.numerical;
        return i;
    }

}
```

I have excluded much of the irrelevant code. This object holds a numerical value but provides a digit by digit reference to a converted format (as we count in base ten this object converts into other base forms)

What I wish is to preserve the current baseNum member and only update the numerical value of my object when using assignment.

As implicit conversion is a static function as far as I know there is no way to access the instance that will be used when assignments are performed after int is casted into my object.

Is there any way to perform this assignment operation in the way I wish?

Again - I already have many methods that allow me to modify the numerical member of the instance.

I also know that I can simply define the baseNum again after assignment.

I only wish to find out if there is a way to possibly utilize my object in the way I am imagining.

Comment: You can't preserve any data because you are not working with `Base` instance.

Comment: Create a Clone() method.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do that.

When you write `b = x`, things happen under the hood are:

1. take the value if `x`
2. invoke `implicit operator Base(int i)` on the value of `x`, a `Base` object is returned
3. assign the returned object to `b`

There is no conventional way you can access the original value of `b` in step 2, where the conversion happens.

Comment: Thank you. This was my exact fear. I will fall back on my customized set method for the numerical member.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to perform this assignment operation in the way I wish?

No, there is not. Conversion operators, implicit or explicit, always return a new object. And in the case of your reference type, the value returned is a reference, and the assignment is to variable holding that reference, which does not in any way modify the object that variable previously referred to.

Furthermore, I would suggest you should not want to do this anyway. An assignment that only modifies the target partially would be very confusing to anyone reading the code. At first, maybe just confusing to people unfamiliar with the design, but eventually, once the code's been sitting there for awhile without any need to work on it, even people who were theoretically well-versed in the design will have trouble remembering that it does this.

Stick with what you already have, where modification of individual components of an object are expressed explicitly. This will keep the code expressive, simple, and easy to understand.

Comment: This is true. I thought that it might be clever and actually reduce complexity but you are right - most people will not assume that this is how my object would function especially after code familiarity reduces over time. I will fall back on my set and get methods for public variables.